# Append error dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm having problems with a dynamic table I've developed, the problem is aesthetic. Every time the user clicks "add product", the code should create a table row and that row should be aligned with the table header. In this code I made, the rows are generated with the correct information, but there is an error in the alignment of the rows.

https://jsfiddle.net/aLnbntmg/

```js
var arrayProduto = [];
var arrayQuantidade = [];

function addItem() {

  var produtoAdicionado = form_vender.seleciona_Produto.value;
  var quantidadeAdionada = parseInt(form_vender.quantidadeVenda.value);
  var achou = false;

  for (i = 0; i < arrayProduto.length; i++) {

    if (arrayProduto[i] == produtoAdicionado) {
      achou = true;
      arrayQuantidade[i] += quantidadeAdionada;
    }
  }

  if (achou == false) {

    arrayProduto.push(produtoAdicionado);
    arrayQuantidade.push(quantidadeAdionada);

  }

  form_vender.quantidadeVenda.value = '';

  $('#tabelavenda').append('<tr class="child"><td>' + produtoAdicionado + '</td><td>' + quantidadeAdionada + '</td></tr>');


}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.tabela {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form_vender">
  <h1> Vender</h1>

  <select id="seleciona_Produto">

    <option value="Uno">Uno</option>
    <option value="Duo">Duo</option>
    <option value="Trilogia">Trilogia</option>
    <option value="Cerveja">Cerveja</option>
    <option value="Refrigerante">Refrigerante</option>
    <option value="Fritas">Fritas</option>
    <option value="Água">Água</option>

  </select>



  <input type="text" size="3" placeholder="Qtde" id="quantidadeVenda">
  <br />
  <br />

</form>

<input type="submit" onclick="addItem()" value="Adicionar item">
<input type="submit" onclick="FinalizaVenda()" value="Finalizar Venda">
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="tabelavenda" class="tabela">
  <table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Identificação</th>
        <th>Porte</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>



  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You are appending outside of table...check generated html....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not appending to the *table* but to the *wrapper* of the table - use this:

```
$('#tabelavenda table').append('<tr class="child"><td>' + produtoAdicionado + '</td><td>' + quantidadeAdionada + '</td></tr>');
```

[`Updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/z3cfdaw3/)

```js
  var arrayProduto = [];
  var arrayQuantidade = [];

  function addItem() {

    var produtoAdicionado = form_vender.seleciona_Produto.value;
    var quantidadeAdionada = parseInt(form_vender.quantidadeVenda.value);
    var achou = false;

    for (i = 0; i < arrayProduto.length; i++) {

      if (arrayProduto[i] == produtoAdicionado) {
        achou = true;
        arrayQuantidade[i] += quantidadeAdionada;
      }
    }

    if (achou == false) {

      arrayProduto.push(produtoAdicionado);
      arrayQuantidade.push(quantidadeAdionada);

    }

    form_vender.quantidadeVenda.value = '';

    $('#tabelavenda table').append('<tr class="child"><td>' + produtoAdicionado + '</td><td>' + quantidadeAdionada + '</td></tr>');


  }
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.tabela {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form_vender">
  <h1> Vender</h1>

  <select id="seleciona_Produto">
    <option value="Uno">Uno</option>
    <option value="Duo">Duo</option>
    <option value="Trilogia">Trilogia</option>
    <option value="Cerveja">Cerveja</option>
    <option value="Refrigerante">Refrigerante</option>
    <option value="Fritas">Fritas</option>
    <option value="Água">Água</option>
  </select>



  <input type="text" size="3" placeholder="Qtde" id="quantidadeVenda">
  <br />
  <br />

</form>

<input type="submit" onclick="addItem()" value="Adicionar item">
<input type="submit" onclick="FinalizaVenda()" value="Finalizar Venda">
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="tabelavenda" class="tabela">
  <table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Identificação</th>
        <th>Porte</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>



  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, dude :)

Answer (score 0):

Change id = "tabelavenda" to  tag like this:

```
<table id="tabelavenda">
```

and delete from the or change the name

```
<div id="other_name">
```